# Web приложение на Java под windows

Tags: windows, java-ee, glassfish, java

Доброго дня!

Случилась у меня необходимость быстро создать простое веб-приложение на Java, которое будет тупо отдавать html страничку и пару скриптов, и при том быстро. Вроде все тривиально... Нет. Увы, но я запутался в обилии java-библиотек и платформ.

Сразу извиняюсь, если вопросы заданы некорректно, но я уверен, вы поймете меня. Человеку, который будет в состоянии дать вразумительный ответ, я буду безмерно благодарен.

Итак, если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно скачать jdk. Какие еще библиотеки мне потребуются?
Как запустить приложение? Нужен ли мне glassfish сервер для этого (я так понимаю, java ЕЕ это и есть он)?

Где можно почитать на русском туториал (для нулевых, вроде меня) по запуску простого java веб-приложения?

Спасибо.

Что ж, придется уточнить. Я не знаю java, у меня 2 стандартных, земных дня (а точнее примерно по 4-5 часов в каждом из них) на то, чтобы написать приложение, отдающее страницу, и нет возможности обстоятельно подойти к изучению. Пожалуйста, не тратьте свое время на написание ответов в стиле "читай мануалы". То, что мне нужно, - описание того, в каком окружении работают web-приложения на java.

Comment: @Angry, но вы в Java-то (без веба) хотя бы можете? Хотя бы на уровне написать консольное приложение и собрать maven-ом?

Comment: Забегая вперед, glassfish, как и прочий Java EE вам не нужен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> То что мне нужно - описание того, в каком окружении работают web приложения на java.

Ну ок. Как правило, самый минимум - это веб-сервер с сервлет-контейнером. Наиболее распространенные это `Apache Tomcat` и `Jetty`. В наиболее стандартном варианте web-приложение представляет собой `WAR`-архив, который разворачивается в сервлет-контейнер. Этот `WAR`-файл содержит дескриптор приложения `web.xml`, описывающий, какие именно сервлеты запускать, сами классы вашего приложения, конфигурационные файлы и статику (картинки и клиентский js).

Сервлет - это особого вида класс (наследующий `HttpServlet`), который умеет отвечать на HTTP-запросы. Непосредственную реализацию того, как он будет отвечать, пишете вы.

Так как отдавать HTML вручную не очень удобно, придумали JSP. Это вроде как "HTML c Java-вставками", напоминающий php-стиль разработки. JSP страница компилируется сервлет-контейнером в сервлет самостоятельно, избавляя вас от рутины.

Вышеописанные вещи это minimum minimorum в рамках спецификаций java web-приложений.

Для того чтобы как-то жить в реальном мире, обычно дальше углубляются либо в Java EE, либо в Spring Framework. И обвешиваются библиотеками, шаблонизаторами, REST-ами, веб-сокетами и прочим.

Comment: @Angry, как определитесь с конкретикой - пишите.

Comment: Это то, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: http://start.spring.io и все, перед этим поставить jdk

Comment: @Mage, я тоже подумывал кинуть ТС эту ссылку, но засомневался. Слишком много вещей на него сразу свалится: maven, spring-ioc, spring mvc, embedded tomcat. А то можно его было бы сразу отправить качать JHipster для полного стека.

Comment: JHipster тут точно не нужен

Answer (score 2):

[[@Angry](/users/32868/angry)](/users/32868/angry) для начала надо выучить саму Яву, выучить стандартный JDK, иначе создание web app на Яве без знания Явы будет похоже на ад. А когда выучишь, качаешь себе простой сервак Apache Tomcat, который будет  `"тупо отдавать html страничку и пару скриптов, и при том быстро"`
[вот тут гайды](http://java-course.ru/student/book1/) для чайников. Только они рассчитаны для тех, кто хоть как-то знает Яву.

А вообще, что ты имеешь в виду словом "скрипт"?  JS? Если тебе надо отдать только пару неизменяемых HTML страниц с JS, то тебе Ява не нужна. Берёшь Apache Http Server, он умеет отдавать простой контент.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Разве что "студенческий отдел кадров" уже несколько старомоден. Сегодня уже нет особых причин использовать JSP и XML для задачи ТС.

Comment: Спасибо, но у вас, видимо, сложилось впечатление,  что я не в курсе даже, что такое js) Спешу уверить, что я хорошо знаком с web-разработкой.
И написать бекенд, ходой/кривой/косой, но на Java - это железобетонное условие. Спасибо за гайд.