# Интернет магазин на java

Tags: java, интернет-магазин

Изучаю Java. Не понимаю некоторых вещей. Сайт ведь пишется на HTML, CSS ну и Javascript. К чему тут Java? Я так понимаю функционал корзины реализуется на java, хранение информации о клиентах... Но за счет чего это реализуется? какие технологии при этом используются? Может есть хороший ресурс где объясняют, как создать такой функционал или интернет-магазин. То есть, как связывается вместе это все? за счет чего? как все это работает? Что почитать, чтобы войти в курс дела, в полный цикл напоминания такого проекта?

Comment: На Java вы можете писать серверную часть приложения. А HTML, CSS и Javascript используется для написания клиентского приложения.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408926/

Answer (score 3):

Когда пользователь делает вызов из браузера к серверу, то без разницы на чем там сервер написан, для браузера эта "черная коробка" которая на запросы отдаёт файлы и данные.

Если html,js,css и картинки статичные, можно отдавать их чем угодно - nginx, Apache Http Server, Tomcat, JBoss/Wildfly, IIS и другие.

Если что-то формируется на лету, то это можно делать с помощью PHP, Perl, Java и т.д. Часто Java используется как бэкенд (работает с данными), а фронтенд (работа со страничками, скриптами, сессиями) пишется на чем-нибудь типа PHP.

Если вы хотите использовать именно Java, вот на вскидку несколько вариантов:

1. Формировать странички в сервелетах или JSP страницах (нужен будет
   контейнер сервлетов, например Apache Tomcat). Если JSP не нравится,
   то в сервлетах можно использовать что-то типа FreeMarker
   (http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/)
2. Если нет желания использовать отдельный контейнер сервлетов, поизучайте Jetty.
3. GWT, JSF

Для данных лучше использовать БД, поэтому изучайте JDBC как минимум. Потом можно перейти к Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно начать с Servlet Api + JSP и JDBC. Так же можете почитать про шаблон MVC. Так же гуглите "популярную литературу по Java" там про это по-любому все есть. Мне как то помогли эти видеоуроки http://dou.ua/forums/topic/10795/ , если Вы хотите написать "сайт на Java" - можете посмотреть оттуда все!)

Comment: Сайт на джава. Я бы не стал так говорить

Comment: @MrGarison ну backend на java,  я так выразился, что бы автору вопроса было понятней...

Comment: Вот так лучше звучит :)